# Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected on the last line instead of }

Tags: c#, debugging

I'm trying to add a gun to my game in unity (with c#)using raycasting but this code isn't working and I keep getting Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected on the last line. I've tried doing multiple things including removing the the end curly brackets and nothing seems to be working and I cant see what's wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour {

    public float damage = 5f;
    public float range = 50f;

    public Camera fpsCam;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
    
        if (input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }

    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
        Debug.log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a compile error. It is so broken the compiler literally has no idea *what you want it to do!* Indeed it is so broken, it can not even tell you where the mistake even is anymore. I can not find any obvious faults in the posted code, but these kinds of errors could be in literally every other part of the sorce code.

Comment: There is so little in that file you might as well just delete it and start over.

Comment: Judging by the message, I'd say you have one too many closing braces `}` in your file

Comment: From quick copy and paste there is nothing wrong with the code. However unity is flakey and temperamental can easily get out of alignment. I would restart your project and IDE, and rebuild it all again

Answer (score 1):

When I checked your code, I only got errors on two typos. "input" and "Debug.log" -> "Input" and "Debug.Log"

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 5f;
    public float range = 50f;
    public Camera fpsCam;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
           Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);
        }
    }
}
```